# Installing packages in python and setting up the working environment

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook

I've been coding with R for quite a while but I want to start learning and using python more for its machine learning applications. However, I'm quite confused as to how to properly install packages and set up the whole working environment. Unlike R where I suppose most people just use RStudio and directly install packages with `install.packages()`, there seems to be a variety of ways this can be done in python, including `pip install` `conda install` and there is also the issue of doing it in the command prompt or one of the IDEs. I've downloaded python 3.8.5 and anaconda3 and some of my most burning questions right now are:

1. When to use which command for installing packages? (and also should I always do it in the command prompt aka cmd on windows instead of inside jupyter notebook)
2. How to navigate the cmd syntax/coding (for example the python documentation for installing packages has this piece of code: `py -m pip install "SomeProject"` but I am completely unfamiliar with this syntax and how to use it - so in the long run do I also have to learn what goes on in the command prompt or does most of the operations occur in the IDE and I mostly don't have to touch the cmd?)
3. How to set up a working directory of sorts (like `setwd()` in R) such that my `.ipynb` files can be saved to other directories or even better if I can just directly start my IDE from another file destination?

I've tried looking at some online resources but they mostly deal with coding basics and the python language instead of these technical aspects of the set up, so I would greatly appreciate some advice on how to navigate and set up the python working environment in general. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Python uses a different way of installing packages. Python has a thing named `venv` which stands for Virtual Environment. You install all of your packages in venv. Usually for each new project you make a new venv.

1. By using Anaconda on windows you install everything within the anaconda environment that you have specified.
2. `python -m pip install "modulename"` is a command that will install `modulename` to your default venv. You will be able to use this module when no other venv is specified. [Here is the docs page.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) [And here is a tutorial on how to use venv](https://python.land/virtual-environments/virtualenv)
3. By default python uses the same directory you have your code in. e.g. `C:/Users/me/home/mypythonfile.py` will run in `C:/Users/me/home/` and will be able to access files in this directory. However you can use `../` to navigate directories or you can specify an absolute path to file you want to open e.g. `with open("C:/system32/somesystemfile.sys") as file`

Comment: Suggest to replace `anaconda` with `conda`. Also `python -m pip install` will not install so a default venv, but will use the python interpreter that is currently found first, so it would be the currently active env.

Comment: How do I create a new virtual environment for each project? And if I have both python installed in my system as well as anaconda, which would be the "default" venv if I install packages using the cmd?

Answer (score 1):

### Going over the technical differences of conda and pip:

So Conda is a packaging tool and installer that aims to do more than what pip does; handle library dependencies outside of the Python packages as well as the Python packages themselves. Both have many similar functionalities as well, you can install packages or create virtual environments with both.

It is generally advisable to generally have both conda and pip installed since there are some packages which might not be available with conda but with pip and vice versa.

The commands to install in both the ways is easy enough, but one thing to keep in mind is that

1. conda stores packages in the `anaconda/pkgs directory`
2. pip stores it in `directory under /usr/local/bin/ for a Unix-based system, or \Program Files\ for Windows`

You can use both pip or conda inside the jupyter notebook, it will work just fine, but it may be possible that you get multiple versions of the same package.

Most of the times, you will use cmd only to install a module used in your code, or to create environments, py -m pip install "SomeProject" here basically means that the module "SomeProject" will be downloaded in base env.

Comment: Your list of installation locations is a bit misleading. If you have an active `conda` env, then both `conda install` and `pip install` will put the python package in the `site-packages` of that env

Comment: Oh yeah my bad, I only meant that for outside any virtual env

Comment: Can I clarify what does the active ```conda``` env mean and where would the packages be stored if I use windows? (aka what is the ```site-packages``` of that env). Also if I do indeed mistakenly get multiple versions of the same package, would that affect their usage and how can I check whether I have multiple versions?

Answer (score 1):

You could think of `conda` as `python` with a variety of additional functionalities, such as certain pre-installed packages and tools, such as `spyder` and `jupyter`. Hence, you must be precise when you say:

> I've downloaded python 3.8.5 and anaconda3

Does it mean you installed python in your computer and then also anaconda?

In general, or at least in my opinion, using anaconda has advantages for development, but typically you'll just use a simple python installation in production (if that applies to you).

Anaconda has it's own package [registry/repository](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/repo) . When you call `conda install <package>`, it will search for the package there and install it if available. You would better search it first, for instance [matplotlib](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/matplotlib).

`pip` is a package manager for the [Python Package Index](https://pypi.org/). `pip` also ships with anaconda. Hence, in an anaconda environment you may install packages from either sources (either using `pip install` or `conda install`). For instance, [pandas from PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/) and [pandas from conda](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pandas). There is no guarantee that packages exist in both sources. You must either search it first or simply try it.

In your first steps, I would suggest you to stick to only one dev env (either simple `python` or `anaconda`, recommend the second). Because that simplifies the question: "which `python` and which `pip` is executed in the cmd line?". That said, those commands should work as expected in any terminal, it be a simple `cmd` or an embedded one like in PyCharm or VS Code.

You could inspect that by running (on windows and linux at least):
`which python`, `which pip`.

Honestly, this is a question/answer that falls outside the scope of SO and for more info you would better check official websites, such as for [anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/) or search for `python vs anaconda` blogs.

Comment: Does this mean that if I use jupyter notebook then I would be using the ```anaconda``` environment and I can run all the codes including ```conda install``` or ```pip install``` in the jupyter notebook without issue?

Comment: @Jeff238 `Jupyter` is based on `IPython`. I am not aware of all that is possible or not in an `IPython` console. `pip install <package>` is one of those, but you would have to search for further info. `Jupyter` is launched from a given `conda env`. By default this is the `base` env. You have to take that into consideration as well to make sure you're in control of where `pip` or `conda` are generating modifications. Obviously you can control this. Read more on `conda` environments and how to activate them in the terminal/cmd. If any of the answers are helping you, you should upvote them.